# Trying to make OutlinedInput have a transparent border, but getting weird artifacts

Tags: css, material-ui, jss

[image]

Trying to create an outlined variant TextField select with a transparent border. The current theme override I have for it is as follows:

```
overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: '#F4F4F4',
        borderRadius: 8,
        height: 56
      },
      notchedOutline: {
        borderColor: 'transparent !important',
        borderRadius: 8,
        borderWidth: '0px !important'
      }
    }
  }
```

However, as seen in the picture, you can see in the picture, there's a weird block artifact around the borders whenever the select is focused.

[image]

I only want it to look like it does in this photo, but as soon as it is focused, it receives those odd edges from the top photo. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with overrides recently too. Material components are usually built with other material components, so you may have to provide overrides to other styles/objects besides `MUIOutlinedInput`.

You may need to customize `MuiInput` and/or `MuiInputBase`.

OR, if you don't want to override all of those, you can create a custom style object and inject it into that component using `withStyles` or `useStyles`